# Dependency issue when updating Xamarin (Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, dependencies, nuget, updates

I have recently updated my Xamarin nuget packages. The update process to the latest version of all packages for Xamarin (core), Xamarin Forms and Xamarin for iOS went really well and everything has updated to the latest version.

Unfortunately most Xamarin.Android.Support.* and Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.* packages are not updating to the latest version because they don't seem compatible with the latest Xamarin version, which does not really make any sense to me.

[image]

I have also just detected the following:

[image]

Does that mean I have to update my MonoAndroid version? If so, how do I do that please?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Set your Android application project's target framework to 7.0 or 7.1

Comment: My target framework is already set to 7.1; The minimum SDK version is 15.

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to update / install the latest Android SDKs using the Android SDK Manager. After installing API 24 and 25, all nuget packages updated successfully.
[image]